# rails backbone.js uncaught type error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, heroku

In my Followers collection inside my backbone app i have the following

```
    window.Curate.Collections.Following = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Curate.Models.User,

      initialize: function (models, options) {
        this.add(models);
        this.user_id = options.user_id;
      },

      url: function () {
        return '/api/users/' + this.user_id + '/following';
      },

      parse: function(response){
            this.page_number = parseInt(response.page_number);
        this.total_pages = parseInt(response.total_pages);
            return response.users;
      }
    });

    window.Curate.Collections.following = new Curate.Collections.Following();
    Curate.Collections.following.fetch({
      data: { page: 1 }
    });
```

whats confusing me is that inside the initialize object  the user_id in options.user_id is throwing an error

```
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined
```

now this does what i want it to do which is to get the user_id so i can put it into the api url but this error occurs which in return wont allow me to push to heroku.

Any idea of what going on here? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't pass any arguments to your collection, actually you don't pass any `options` object

```
new Curate.Collections.Following();
```

It should be something like this and includes `options` object with `user_id`

```
new Curate.Collections.Following([{}, {}], { user_id: 123 });
```

P.S. this line inside `initialize` method of `Backbone.Collection` is not necessary

```
this.add(models);
```

because Backbone automatically resets collection with passed in array of models in [constructor](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-85) after initialize.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i had the new collection statement in my routes fill but i had an unnecessary id: parseInt(id) instead of just user_id: id